# Squish is not recognizing object

Tags: python, squish

I'm trying to import objects from an external file. The Object is not stored in Object map.

Definition:

```
    shutterMultiplier = waitForObject({"name": "UserVisible/Capturing 
    Settings/Basic/Shutter Multiplier.AHBox<int>.SpinBox", "type": "QSpinBox", 
    "visible": 1})
```

This is working correctly. However, when I try it with:

```
    shutterMultiplier = findObject({"name": name, "type": type, "visible": 1})
```

When

```
   name = UserVisible/Capturing Settings/Basic/Shutter Multiplier.AHBox<int>.SpinBox
   type = QSpinBox
```

I only get `LookUpError` about not recognized properties. I also tried the option with name and typed in `""`. The list of missing properties is not populated. Is there any way how to make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was not the syntax. Solution was to save correct syntax and kill the application and all created instances. Also there helped to make it strings without `"`.

```
    str(testData.field(sample, "name"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try assigning properties for name as follows:

name = {"UserVisible/Capturing Settings/Basic/Shutter Multiplier.AHBox.SpinBox", "type": "QSpinBox", "visible": 1}

I believe visible:1 is occurrence of some sort, see if you can find alternative properties which can be robust.As you keep adding objects, your list gets bigger so does your occurrence.

Comment: define "name" on a separate global file and import this global file at the start of your program.

Comment: Defining it in global file is the last option. Whole idea is to avoid definition in global files and be able to define objects by names provided from developers. Visible: 1 is property provided by Squish and is not required for functioning. Removing it does not affect functionality at all.

Comment: Squish's "visible" property is a boolean value in general, but needs to be encoded as an integer (depending on Squish edition), where 1 stands for "true", and 0 for "false".